# php check if browser tab was opened with "target=" - and what target it was

Tags: php

I am opening two windows in one session, which should have different behaviours. As the windows open at the same time, they are using th same options and interfering with each other. Therefore I would need to check in the code, how they were opened.

If it was opened with something like

```
window.open(href, target='pdf');
```

I would want to check this

```
if(tab.target = "pdf")
 {
  $check_target = 1
 }
else
 {
  $check_target = 2
 }
```

now "tab.target" does not exist - can I achieve this somehow?

Thanks!
Max

Answer (score 0):

I would add a something to the url like this:

```
window.open(href+'?mytarget=pdf', target='pdf');
```

Then in your php code:

```
if($_GET['mytarget'] == "pdf")
 {
  $check_target = 1;
 }
else
 {
  $check_target = 2;
 }
```

Comment: If you are clicking the same button to open a new window, you could add some javascript to change the mytarget variable every time the button is clicked.